# Cron-like task using background fetch in iOS7

Tags: ios, background, ios7, fetch

I am trying to implement a long running background cron-like task in iOS7. The way I have it working now is a repeating timer that runs at a frequency less than 10 minutes, then starts and stops locationManager's startUpdatingLocation at predefined intervals:

```
/*
 * Very important, this function is called once a minute in the background and it specifies what          actions to take based on the number of minutes passed.
 */
-(void)everyMinuteAction
{
    NSLog(@"Every minute action");
    if ([_killTime timeIntervalSinceNow] < 0.0)
    {
        //App is dead, long live the app!
        _appKilledDueToInactivity = YES;

        //Do some stuff to indicate to the user on the UI that they should not


    }

    //Once every n minutes, we need to turn on the GPS and report our location with four points.
    NSLog(@"Modulus: %d", numberOfMinutesPassedSinceAppStarted % (int)floor((double)currentTTL/60.0));

    if ((numberOfMinutesPassedSinceAppStarted % (int)floor((double)currentTTL/60.0) == 0) || numberOfMinutesPassedSinceAppStarted == 0)
    {
        //Treat it differently if we are in foreground or background
        //GPS only responds with locations quickly when in foreground, so give it a bit more time if it is in the background.
        if (inBackground)
        {
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:140 target:self selector:@selector(killGPSAfterCertainTime) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        } else {
            //Start a timer that will kill the GPS after a certain period of time, regardless of how many points it has.
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:80 target:self selector:@selector(killGPSAfterCertainTime) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        }




        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

        //Control is now passed on to didUpdateLocations, which will turn off location tracking after either a set period of time or a set number of
        //locations received.

        self.timeSpentFartassingAroundTryingToGetLocations = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        self.numberOfLocationsCollectedThisTTL = 0;
    }

    if (3 % numberOfMinutesPassedSinceAppStarted == 0)
    {
        //Every 3 minutes we need to do some talking to the server
    }


    //Increment this, we've been using the app for another minute.
    numberOfMinutesPassedSinceAppStarted += 1;
}
```

Turns out that this gets killed after 10 minutes if the TTL is bigger than 10 minutes, and I'm not entirely sure if it works with the background location permission enabled in my plist file, either.

I'm wondering if I would be able to use the new fetch network information background task in order to implement this - simply by changing the signature of the method and registering for that service every 60 seconds. Based on the number of minutes passed I could choose whether to either check for some information over the network, or to do some gps funny business.

The next question would be whether specifying a 60 second interval on the fetch api will actually guarantee me an update every 60 seconds? Or will there be significant drift?

Comment: Did you get any further here?

Comment: This approach was mandated by the client, but it always ended up with the app crashing out. We used a more apple oriented approach (major location changes) and it fixed the issue.